# Multiple dynamic pipelines serving as input to multiple mountpoints on a gstreamer rtsp server

Tags: sockets, gstreamer, rtsp

I have a scenario where currently the following is implemented:

- a gstreamer pipeline outputting processed video to a udp port
- a gstreamer rtsp server consuming from the udp port and exposing it as a mount point based rtsp stream.

Now I need to extend this paradigm to multiple such instances, may be 100s or 1000s. And I feel that using a udp port is not reliable since making a udp port based association between the pipeline and the rtspserver mount point  for each such pipeline means I need to maintain a map of which pipeline goes to which udp port and also I need to dynamically generate/allocate the udp port numbers  to each such pipeline.

What are the alternatives here - I thought of using a named pipe or unix domain sockets since both pipeline and rtsp server will reside on the same machine - but that failed as it required that both the pipeline and the server run simultaneously all the time and if either the pipeline or the server drops, the other gets stuck/blocked in the write/read call on the pipe/socket.

Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide the pipelines you've already got?